# Note written on the visa by hand when entering US

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I got my 10-year US visa type `B1/B2` on 13 Feb 2013. Shortly after, when entering the US, the CBP officer wrote **B2 13 Feb 2014** with an ink pen on the passport page next to my visa.

What does this note mean? I was not given any explanation, nor I had problems entering and leaving US back then.

Comment: It is usually the expiration date of your I-94, which basically shows the duration of allowed stay in the country. So nothing to worry about. I have a whole page of written note for my German Visa (work permit), and does not create any problems.

Answer (score 4):

The notation is normally written on top of the CBP stamp that indicates when you were admitted to the US.  The stamp has two blank lines, one labeled *class* and the other labeled *until.*

The notation indicates that you were admitted in B-2 status ("class"), *until* the 13th of February, 2014.  That notation concerns only your first entry. After you leave the US, when you enter the next time, you'll get a new stamp with a new "until" date.  With each entry, the class will either be B1 or B2, depending on the purpose of that trip as described to the immigration officer.